# Given $\log(p(x)) = q(x)$ are $p$ and $q$ algebraically independent?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendental-equations

Since $e^x$ and $\log y$ are transcendental functions, does $$\log p(x) = q(x)$$ mean that polynomials $p$ and $q$ (of finite degree $n$ and $m$ respectively) are algebraically independent?

What happens if we allow $n,m\longrightarrow\infty$ ?

Comment: Do you know many polynomials $p$ such that $\log p$ is a polynomial as well?

Comment: And by let $n,m \to \infty$ what do you mean?  Entire functions?  Maybe that question is interesting...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, consider the following: If $p$ and $q$ are polynomials related via $e^{q(x)} = p(x)$, then $q$ must be a constant polynomial; this can be seen by noting that $e^x$ grows faster than any polynomial.

We also see that $p$ must also be constant.

Comment: So if $p$ and $q$ are not constant then they must be algebraically independent. Thanks. This is what I thought.

Comment: "So if p and q are not constant then they must be algebraically independent". No.

Comment: @pbs If $p$ and $q$ are not constant, then the desired property cannot hold.

Comment: That's exactly my point. If $p$ and $q$ are not constants, then there is no way that we can relate $p$ to $q$ algebraically using the equation $e^{q(x)}=p(x)$.